# Prove the sign of $\sigma$ equals $\prod_{1\leq i < j \leq n} \dfrac{\sigma(j)-\sigma(i)}{j-i}.$

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, permutations

> How can one prove that for a permutation $\sigma$ of $\{1,\cdots, n\}$, the sign of $\sigma$ equals $\prod_{1\leq i < j \leq n} \dfrac{\sigma(j)-\sigma(i)}{j-i}?$ The sign of a permutation is the parity of the number of transpositions it can be written as.

Let ${\rm Inv}(\sigma)$ denote the number of inversions of $\sigma$.
From [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4038393/product-formula-for-sign-of-permutation), $(-1)^{{\rm Inv}(\sigma)} = \prod_{1\leq i < j \leq n} \dfrac{\sigma(j)-\sigma(i)}{j-i},$ so one method is to prove that the sign equals $(-1)^{{\rm Inv}(\sigma)}$. Though I think there's a more direct approach that doesn't use the equality given by that formula. Also, I know that all permutations have a representation as a product of disjoint cycles and that every permutation is either even or odd but not both. I'm not sure if the claim can be proven by induction on $n$, the number of elements the permutation is acting on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's define $\varphi : \sigma \mapsto \displaystyle\prod_{1\leq i < j \leq n} \dfrac{\sigma(j)-\sigma(i)}{j-i}$.

1. We prove that $\varphi(\sigma \circ \tau)=\varphi(\sigma) \varphi(\tau)$. Indeed,
   \begin{align*} \varphi(\sigma \circ \tau) & =  \prod_{1\leq i < j \leq n} \dfrac{\sigma \circ \tau(j)-\sigma\circ \tau(i)}{j-i}\\& =  \prod_{1\leq i < j \leq n} \dfrac{\sigma \circ \tau(j)-\sigma\circ \tau(i)}{\tau(j)-\tau(i)} \times \dfrac{\tau(j)-\tau(i)}{j-i}\\& =  \prod_{1\leq i < j \leq n} \dfrac{\sigma \circ \tau(j)-\sigma\circ \tau(i)}{\tau(j)-\tau(i)} \times \prod_{1\leq i < j \leq n}\dfrac{\tau(j)-\tau(i)}{j-i}\\& =  \prod_{1\leq i < j \leq n} \dfrac{\sigma (j)-\sigma(i)}{j-i} \times \prod_{1\leq i < j \leq n}\dfrac{\tau(j)-\tau(i)}{j-i}\\&=\varphi(\sigma)\varphi(\tau)
    \end{align*}
2. We prove that if $\tau$ is a transposition, then $\varphi(\tau)=-1$. Indeed, if $\tau$ is the $(i,j)$ transposition, then
   $$\varphi(\tau)= -\prod_{k \neq i,j}\dfrac{\tau(k)-\tau(i)}{k-i}\dfrac{\tau(k)-\tau(j)}{k-j} =-\prod_{k \neq i,j}\dfrac{k-j}{k-i}\dfrac{k-i}{k-j} = -1 $$
3. The result directly follows from the two points above.

Comment: The third row, first factor =  the fourth row, first factor . That is not obvious and has to be justified.

Comment: @orangeskid One has $$\prod_{1\leq i < j \leq n} \dfrac{\sigma \circ \tau(j)-\sigma\circ \tau(i)}{\tau(j)-\tau(i)} = \prod_{\lbrace i,j \rbrace \subset \lbrace 1, ..., n \rbrace} \dfrac{\sigma \circ \tau(j)-\sigma\circ \tau(i)}{\tau(j)-\tau(i)}$$ so you can make the substitution $i \rightarrow \tau(i)$ and $j \rightarrow \tau(j)$ to get directly $$\prod_{\lbrace i,j \rbrace \subset \lbrace 1, ..., n \rbrace} \dfrac{\sigma(j)-\sigma(i)}{j-i}$$ which is equivalent to $$\prod_{1\leq i < j \leq n} \dfrac{\sigma(j)-\sigma(i)}{j-i}$$

Comment: I see, you are considering the associated map from $\mathcal{P}_2(\{1,2, \ldots, n\})$ to itself. At each point you have a sign... ( like the sign of the derivative). Then take the product of all those signs. It is getting clearer. Anyhow, the sign of a permutation is not an obvious notion, I wonder if they thought about it before determinants.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the polynomial in $n$ variables given by  $\prod_{1\leq i < j \leq n} (x_j-x_i)$ and the obvious action that $S_n$ has on the indices of those variables. It is not hard to see that a transposition acts on that polynomial by changing the sign since $x_i-x_j=-(x_j-x_i)$. This means for some permutation $\sigma$ we have that $$(-1)^{\rm Inv {(\sigma})}\displaystyle\prod_{1\leq i < j \leq n} (x_j-x_i) = \displaystyle\prod_{1\leq i < j \leq n} (x_{\sigma(j)}-x_{\sigma(i)})$$ which gives us that $$(-1)^{\rm Inv {(\sigma})}=\displaystyle\prod_{1\leq i < j \leq n} \frac{x_{\sigma(j)}-x_{\sigma(i)}}{x_j-x_i}$$

and the result follows as a corollary.

Comment: Can you justify why a transposition changes the sign? I didn't actually mention this in my post since I realized this after posting, but I was only able to prove that a transposition changes the sign when $x_1 < x_2<\cdots < x_n.$ Though I'm pretty sure that the proof for a general permutation should be similar, I'd prefer if you gave the details if possible.

Comment: Also I don't understand why $(-1)^{Inv(\sigma)} \prod_{1\leq i < j\leq n} (x_j-x_i) = \prod_{1\leq i < j\leq n} (x_{\sigma(j)}-x_{\sigma(i)}$. I know every permutation has a disjoint cycle representation. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: @user33096 As it says the change of sign for a transposition follows from $x_i-x_j=-(x_j-x_i)$. Note that by construction each transposition acts on exactly one term in the product and stabilizes the rest. For example if we look at $S_3$ the polynomial is $(x_3-x_1)(x_3-x_2)(x_2-x_1)$ and you can see how each distinct transposition is represented by one term in the polynomial. Note too that the values of $x_k$ can be completely arbitrary as long as for $i \neq k$ then $x_i \neq x_k$ so we avoid division by zero. They could even be complex number which can't be ordered.

Comment: I think the first answer covers why a transposition changes the sign. As for the equivalence, [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_a_permutation) provides some details. Thanks for your answer (+!)!